# QuickSort implementation does not work for duplicate key

Tags: c, quicksort

I tried to implement Quicksort. It works fine except when there is a duplicate key, in which case there is an infinite loop and it never terminates. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```c
// quick sort
void quickSort(int arr[], const unsigned size)
{
    // base case
    if (size < 2)
        return;

    int pivot = arr[size / 2];
    unsigned L = 0, U = size - 1;

    // partitioning
    while (L < U) {
        while (arr[L] < pivot)
            L++;
        while (arr[U] > pivot)
            U--;

        swap(&arr[L], &arr[U]);
    }

    quickSort(arr, L); // sort left array
    quickSort(&arr[U + 1], size - L - 1); // sort right array
}
```

Comment: Change the two inner tests to `<=` and `>=` respectively.

Comment: Values that are equal to the pivot value should be left in place.

Comment: When you have 2 or more equal keys L will never be equal to U because they will never progress. Change the `<`, `>` to `<=`, `>=`.

Comment: @רועיאבידן If I do so, I get a segmentation fault, probably because it is possible for L to never stops incrementing and U to never stop decrementing.

Comment: Right, you'll have to guard against running off the ends of the array in the inner loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the *less than* and *greater than* conditions. But there is no condition for `=`. This is why it will run an infinite loop. Change them to `<=`  and `>=`.