# My MergeSort code doesn't do any change on the array

Tags: c++

The result of it is:

### 7 1 0 9 1 5 9 4 7 3

### 7 1 0 9 1 5 9 4 7 3

It doesn't do any change on the original array.I have checked the parts on merge and mergesort many times.I just can't find what's the problem.How can I improve my code? Or any suggestions on improving my coding level, I am just a collage student. Thanks for your attention and advice!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
void Merge(int* A,int left,int mid,int right){
    int i,j,k;
    int n1=mid-left+1;
    int n2=right-mid;
    //create the temprorte array
    int* L=(int*)malloc(n1*sizeof(int));
    int* R=(int*)malloc(n2*sizeof(int));
    //use a loop to merge
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
        L[i]=A[left+i];
    }
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
        R[j]=A[mid+1+j];
    }
    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r] */
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = left; // Initial index of merged subarray
    for (; i < n1 && j < n2; k++) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(; i < n1; i++, k++){
        A[k] = L[i];
    }
    for(; j < n2; j++, k++){
        A[k] = R[j];
    }

    free(L);
    free(R);
} 
void MergeSort(int* A,int left,int right){
    if(right<left){
        int mid=left+(right-left)/2;
        MergeSort(A,left,mid);
        MergeSort(A,mid+1,right);
        Merge(A, left, mid, right);
    }
}
int main(){
    int* arrME;//array for merge sort;
    int n1=10;
    arrME=(int*)malloc(n1*sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        int r=rand()%10;
        arrME[i]=r;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        cout<<arrME[i]<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
    MergeSort(arrME,0,n1-1);
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        cout<<arrME[i]<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: I cannot understand the description you give in your question, and there is no link with the code which at least do not have the *main* and *InsertSort* you speak about

Comment: What did you learn after using your debugger?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius  Thanks for both of your suggestions.Sorry it's my first time to use this website.I have updated my code.Would you plz have a look?

Comment: @StephenNewell It didn't display any bug. Just the two array I show above, which doesn't make any change to the original array.

Comment: The code looks like C code, and not like (idiomatic) C++ code.

Comment: is a kind of quicksort ?

Comment: @ Eljay Well, it is c++ code,I coped some parts of it from my professor's answer.

Comment: @bruno Yes,this is what we are learning.

Comment: *MergeSort* does nothing because the test is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in *main* you call

> ```
> MergeSort(arrME,0,n1-1);
> ```

but in

> ```
> void MergeSort(int* A,int left,int right){
>    if(right<left){
> ```

the test is false so you exit the function immediately

Reversing it (`if(left<right)`) gives the expected result

Examples of execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
9 0 6 8 0 6 5 6 4 8 
0 0 4 5 6 6 6 8 8 9 
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ 

bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
7 8 9 4 3 2 6 3 3 4 
2 3 3 3 4 4 6 7 8 9 
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

---

However you do not need to allocate 2 sub arrays each time, you can work in the array to sort directly

Comment: Thank you! It should be right>left. OMG it is such a silly mistake...

Comment: @Jane_IDK yes it is. It is easy to detect executing in a debugger. Out of that you do not need to allocate temporary arrays, doing that is very expensive, for instance look at that very recent question about quicksort : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458555/quicksort-implementation-does-not-work-for-duplicate-key